# Adding headers to http get request on Angular 5

Tags: angular, http-headers

I am adding Authorization header to a `get` request on Angular5.
I was sure i was doing this correctly, but for some reason i dont see my newly appended headers in the request.
Pls note that i am using a deprecated version of Http, the `from '@angular/http';`
As far as i know this should not be the cause of the problem, but its a lrge project and i cannot decide myself to update/replace the libraries used at the moment.
My code:

`var localUrl = THE_URL
    let token = localStorage.getItem('THE_TOKEN');
    console.log(token)//token logged succesfully
    let headers : Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization',token);
    let opts = new RequestOptions();
    opts.headers = headers;
    console.log(opts)// Opts printed, contains headers 
    return this.http.get(localUrl,opts).toPromise().then(res => {
      //DO SOMETHING WITH DA GET REQUEST
      }
      return res.json();
    }).catch(this.handleErrorResponse);
  }`

The request is not failing, but its sent to the data provider service @`localUrl` without the authorization.
The console:
[image]
So as you can see here above my log statement, the authorization header is there, also, here the intercepted request, there is no header sent, apparently i am adding it wrongly, any advise?
[image]

Comment: If you're upgrading to angular 5 without upgrading to HttpClient, you will run into a few problems. Recommend switching from Http to HttpClient if possible.

Comment: I will request that now

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation, except that I am fully in Angular 5, with `HttpClient`. I have the exact same display in the console and utterly fail to be authenticated in the back-end. FYI, my back-end is a simple spring-boot 2 app, using spring sec 5.